# Deleter's calling context

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

is it possible for a C++ Deleter used with the standard smart pointers to determine the context in which it has been called?

Let's say freeing my resource may generate an error.

If my resource gets freed during stack unwinding I obviously do not want my Deleter to throw an exception in case of an error. But if the Deleter was called using reset(), then reporting the error to the user of my code is fine.

```
struct MyDeleter
{
  typedef ... pointer;

  void operator ()(pointer p)
  {
    if (release_p_failed)
    {
      if (throwing_exception_is_ok)
        throw ...;
      else
        hide_error_to_not_abort;
    }
  }
};
```

Example

```
{
  std::unique_ptr<..., MyDeleter> p{ ..., MyDeleter };

  // A:
  p.reset(); // User intends to handle the error. Throwing exception is ok.

  // B: Leave scope and do not throw an exception in case of an error.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about throwing an exception during stack un-winding you should use [std::uncaught_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception), e.g.

```
struct MyDeleter
{
  typedef ... pointer;

  void operator ()(pointer p)
  {
    if (release_p_failed)
    {
      if (!std::uncaught_exception())   // no stack unwinding in progress
        throw ...;
      else
        hide_error_to_not_abort;
    }
  }
};
```

This is the standard idiom to use if you ever need to throw from any destructor. 
Of course, this cannot distinguish between being called from `std::unique_ptr::~std::unique_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr::reset()`, though.

Note that from C++17 `std::uncaught_exception` is deprecated and replaced by `std::uncaught_exceptions`, returning the number of uncaught exceptions currently 'in the air'.

Comment: This would still allow the deleter to throw an exception as a result of normal destruction. AFAICT, OP only wants `reset` to be able to do this...

Comment: @defube I'm not sure the OP was after the distinction between `std::unique_ptr::~std::unique_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr::reset()`, but between stack unwinding and not stack unwinding.

Comment: OP's example explicitly requires that `~unique_ptr` not throw: "Leave scope and do not throw an exception in case of an error."

Comment: My initial interest was to find out whether the standard smart pointers support an interface similar to the DBConnection class in Scott Meyer's Item 8: Prevent exceptions from leaving destructors. (One method to deal with the error and a destructor that cleans up but does not throw)

Comment: If there are no exceptions "in-flight", this will still allow the deleter to throw an exception during the destruction of its `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @defube Yes, we all know that and I actually make that point in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, `unique_ptr` does not provide any way to determine the invocation context of the deleter.

You will need to provide separate cleanup logic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::uncaught_exception()` to distinguish normal destruction from stack unwinding.